# Правильно ли я понимаю основную функцию для которой Wake lock был создан?

Tags: android

Wake lock - блокирует переход в спящий режим, либо только процессор, либо экран и процессор - это ясно, а вот блокирует ли он весь процессор или лишь даёт конкретному приложению воспользоваться им в спящем режиме, если приложение включило в коде Wake lock? этого я не знаю.

Ведь логичнее, в спящем режиме снижать нагрузку на процессор почти до 0 ограничивая возможность приложений выполнять свой код, если оно не включило Wake Lock, а не полностью останавливать процессор, всё таки есть же ещё сама ОС Android и её службы, тот же AlarmManager.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby - здесь описано как работает система в неактивном режиме. Блокировка не позволяет перейти в спящий режим самой системе - соответственно все ресурсы будут доступны всем приложениям. Логика такая: пусть они все выполнят свои задачи в активном режиме, чем будут потом по одному без конца будить устройство ради своих задач.

Comment: И ещё вопрос, doze mode не распространяется на приложения чью активность разрешено не конролировать, т.е если в белый список занести?

Comment: doze mode распространяется на всех. Не знаю что там за белый список, но скорее всего речь идёт о фоновой активности в принципе. То есть сможет ли приложение вообще работать без видимых пользователю признаков активности даже когда устройство пребывает в активном режиме.

Comment: Да, именно. Я имел ввиду список приложений которые работают в фоне без ограничений в doze mode